# Specify Storage Account for Azure Function via KeyVault

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I want to use a separate storage account for my function app

I will be having several function apps and I want to have the storage connection strings in KeyVault.  As there will be multiple apps I want to use the convention of AzureWebJobsStorage-FunctionApp1, AzureWebJobsStorage-FunctionApp2, etc

The screenshot below shows the config settings I have

[image]

I have AzureWebJobsStorage config setting which contains

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=myvault;SecretName=AzureWebJobsStorage-FunctionApp1)
```

I went into KeyVault and set this key to be xx.  This should have totally broken the function app given that its web storage account is invalid, but it didnt, even after I restarted the App

What am I doing wrong as it does seem like this is being ignored?

Im thinking that it must be using WEBSITE_AZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING but I always thought Azure Functions use AzureWebJobsStorage?

If I follow the same process for WEBSITE_AZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING it still works even with an invalid connection!

Paul

Comment: *then on purpose broke the key my keyvault* How? Did you check the old version is disabled and the new one enabled?

Comment: Did you restart the app, so that it picks up the new configuration?

Comment: Yep old version disabled and new one enabled.  I restarted too.  I published from a local machine is there a change that "UseDevelopmentStorage=true got through?  I thought that would never get to the portal

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your configuration settings from azure portal, you can remove all sensitive info

Comment: ok I have added more info

Comment: Interestingly I have seen a link to the storage account in a totally different config setting!